# Using Alexa Skill to create a To-Do list with initial items

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

So I'm working on creating an Alexa Skill where the user can say: "Alexa, ask _____ what items should I bring for my trip?" and she will respond with "You should bring x, y, z. I made a to-do list in your Alexa App with these items".

I want the skill to make a to-do list that creates the list, and populates it with a few items that Alexa suggests. Here is what I have so far:

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

function createList(intentName, accessToken, itemArray, callback) {
    var date = moment().tz("America/New_York").format('l');
    var lms = new Alexa.services.ListManagementService();
    var listId;
    var listObject = {

        'name': intentName + " " + date,
        "state": "active"
    };
    lms.createList(listObject, accessToken, (data) => {
        console.log(data.listId);
        for (listItem in itemArray) {
            var listItemObject = {
                'value': itemArray[listItem],
                'status': 'active'
            };
            console.log(listItemObject);
            lms.createListItem(data.listId, listItemObject, accessToken);
        }
        callback();
    })
}
```

EDIT:

When I run the skill, the list is created, but none of the list items are instantiated. It says "item is not defined". What do I need to do in order to create the list and also have the list items created in the same step?

Comment: And what is the question? What doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I apologize, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

I've been tinkering and found a solution that is allowing me to get what I need.

```
    function createList(intentName, accessToken, itemArray, callback) {
        var date = moment().tz("America/New_York").format('l');
        var lms = new Alexa.services.ListManagementService();
        var listId;
        var count = 0;


        var listObject = {
            'name': intentName + " " + date,
            "state": "active"
        }
        lms.createList(listObject, accessToken)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                itemArray.forEach(function (item) {
                    var listItemObject = {
                        'value': item,
                        'status': 'active'
                    }
                    lms.createListItem(data.listId, listItemObject, accessToken)
                       .then(count++);
                });

                if (count == itemArray.length) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error caught: " + error.message);
                var resError = JSON.parse(error.message)
                switch (resError.type) {
                    case "NameConflict":
                        callback();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
    }
```

I think the problem was that the callback was firing before the items had all finished being created so I just forced them to complete before calling it.

I'm sure there is a better and cleaner way, but this is just what worked for me. Let me know what I can improve on.